# Orientation issues (landscape) with TouchID authentication

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation, touch-id

We are using TouchID for our iPad app, which supports both Portrait &  Landscape orientation.
According to our understanding, the TouchID authentication dialog doesn't support Landscape orientation, which is still fine; however, upon turning the screen to landscape mode, the TouchID dialog remains in portrait mode, but the viewcontroller also fails to rotate to landscape! Besides, the statusbar rotates to landscape mode, giving an ugly look.

We have observed the similar behavior on iTunes too. Please advice if this is the standard behaviour or is there any other way to solve the issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem in my app. It seems that Touch ID dialogue prevents view controller under from getting information about device rotation. I tested it on App Store - tried to buy app. When dialogue appeared on dialogue rotate, App Store didn't react to device rotation.

Tested on iOS 10.2 (14C92)